# Android app not supporting different devices: HTC, Motorola g2, S5 etc

Tags: android, installation, device, android-screen-support

I developed an Android app. I am trying to install on different devices. I can install on some of the devices like samsung s2, samsung s3 and s3 mini.
 But, I can't install in other devices like HTC, Motorola g2, S5 etc. 
Please give me some suggestions to get rid from this problem.

Comment: That must be the problem with the sdk version. What is your maxsupported version of your app?

Comment: The target version is "21", you can see my code:                                <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: @sree7k7 Can you explain "can't install", through what ways have you tried installing it

Comment: Now, I have samsung s2, I am able to install app in that mobile it's working . I have another mobile HTC one after installing app, it's not working showing that: application is stopped due to error.

Comment: Post the log message so we can take a look at the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to you not having the driver software on your computer for those devices. Unless there is an error when the APK itself fails to install.

Comment: I have tried with the drivers. The application is installing in other devices like HTC one, but the problem is: it's not working properly. showing error. And I installed the same app in samsung s2 and it's working properly.